# How to Increase and Decrease the Font Size of Awesome CV by posqiut0?

Tags: formatting, fontsize, overleaf, resume, awesome-cv

How can I increase the font size of bullet points in the [Awesome CV resume](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine the environment for `cvitems`. Add before `\begin{document}`

```
% Redefine the environment for cvitems
\renewenvironment{cvitems}{%
    \vspace{-4.0mm}
    \begin{justify}
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
            \normalsize % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
            \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
        }{%
        \end{itemize}
    \end{justify}
    \vspace{-4.0mm}
}
```

You can try changing `\normalisize` to `\large`.

[image: b]